# Use data binding to set View visibility

Tags: android, android-databinding

Trying to set visibility of `View` using custom variable, but error occurs: `Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. visible is missing it`. Is it possible to set view visibility using data binding? Thanks.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="sale"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</data>

<FrameLayout android:visibility="@{sale ? visible : gone}"/>
```

Comment: Refer [Android Data Binding: visibility on include tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723823/android-data-binding-visibility-on-include-tag)

Answer (score 348, accepted):

As stated in the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#expression_language), you need to do it like this:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="sale"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</data>

<FrameLayout android:visibility="@{sale ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```

Comment: and how to set value to "sale"?

Comment: So you mean how to assign the value "sale" to a String variable?

Comment: exactly! I'm facing issue. Please share I will compare and then let you know.

Comment: Damn it! How I missed the Silly *import*. Done, thanks.

Comment: Hey! any idea why *position* glitch on scroll? [Adapter](https://paste.ofcode.org/38HVLLLMa9mUZMxq9BfMSeh)

Comment: I can not see any issue with the code, but I doubt that this is enough to analyse your problem. Maybe you can provide me a fully running example which I could test (e.g. a sample GitHub repo)?

Comment: @RobinHood from your activity or fragment.
example for activity
```
boolean isSale = true;
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setSale(isSale);
```

Comment: I am the 222th click

Answer (score 70):

In your layout:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="...."/>
</data>


<View
 android:layout_width="10dp"
 android:layout_height="10dp"
 android:visibility="@{viewModel.saleVisibility, default=gone}"/>
```

In your ViewModel java code:

```
@Bindable
public int getSaleVisibility(){
 return mSaleIndecator ? VISIBLE : GONE;
}
```

Comment: you saved me from a minor headache

Comment: Your data model have to be Observable for that to work.

Comment: this worked for me *without* including `@Bindable`.  When I included that I was getting different binding errors, including suggestion to extend `BaseObservable`. Good pointer here

Comment: Must be the accepted answer ! It's worked for me perfectly !

Comment: Any suggestion for `LiveData<Boolean>`?

Answer (score 51):

The problem is that `visibility` is an `Integer` on the `View` class, this means you have two ways to make this work:

1. Use the `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE` constants. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#imports
2. Define a custom setter for `visibility` that takes a `Boolean`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters

Possible implementation:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
public static void setVisibility(View view, Boolean value) {
    view.setVisibility(value ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

Which will make `<FrameLayout android:visibility="@{sale}"/>` work.

Comment: Where it is convenient for you, the annotation processor automatically detects them during compilation.

Comment: Thank you, I put it in my BindingUtils.java

Comment: but how to set value sale?

Comment: how can I apply same approach to <include tags?

Comment: @EslamWael74 you set the value of sale via the binding in your Java/Kotlin code. Something like val binding = MyClassBinding.inflate(...), and then you can just call binding.sale = true.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to [Kiskae](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44420565/2914140) solution. Put this method in a separate file, for instance, Bindings.kt:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
fun View.bindVisibility(visible: Boolean?) {
    isVisible = visible == true
    // visibility = if (visible == true) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Then in layout XML:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="SomeViewModel" />
</data>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.number == 1}" />
```