# Android databinding cannot work with visibility in <include> tag

Tags: android, data-binding, include, visibility

```
<layout>
  <data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.foo.ViewModel"/>
  </data>
  ...
  <include
     layout="@layout/widget_parents_details"
     android:visibility="@{viewModel.fooVisibility}"/>
   ...
</layout>
```

```
class ViewModel: ViewModel()  {
  val fooVisibility = MutableLiveData(View.GONE)
}
```

The problem is that this `android:visibility="@{viewModel.fooVisibility}"` works fine in other `View`s including `<LinearLayout>`. However, when it is used in  tag, it returns below error

`error: incompatible types: MutableLiveData<Integer> cannot be converted to int`

Comment: Hello @Myrick Chow have you checked this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723823/android-data-binding-visibility-on-include-tag/35756946

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe Google error message is so misleading.

Comment: so your problem is resolve.