# Use data binding - change visibility using boolean operator

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

So I have a view:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/root"
        layout="@layout/layout_awesome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isVisible="@{viewModel.itemA != null}" />
```

But in my case, root view visibility should be determined based on two model values in my viewmodel, so I would like to achieve something like this:

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/root"
        layout="@layout/layout_awesome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isVisible="@{viewModel.itemA != null && viewModel.itemB == null}" />
```

However, this does not work. Is there an issue with the syntax? I could not find an example where operators are used.

Comment: Can you try like this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35756946/5696047

Comment: That's not exactly what I want to achieve, sadly. I want to make sure boolean operator can be used in this case.

Comment: apologies for miscommunication ... 
What i am trying to say that instead of this ```app:isVisible="@{viewModel.itemA != null && viewModel.itemB == null}"``` use this ```bind:isVisible="@{viewModel.itemA != null && viewModel.itemB == null}"``` and inside ```layout_awesome``` , try this ```android:visibility="@{isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"``` in your code

Comment: You should replace the && operator with `&amp;&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the logical operators like this :

```
'&' --> '&amp;'

'<' --> '&lt;'

'>' --> '&gt;'
```

So, the correct xml will be this :

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/root"
        layout="@layout/layout_awesome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:isVisible="@{viewModel.itemA != null &amp;&amp; viewModel.itemB == null}" />
```

reference :
[android databinding using "&&" logical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152824/android-databinding-using-logical-operator)